# Python "UnicodeEncodeError" error on Turkish characters

Tags: python, python-unicode

I'm making a discord bot and in somewhere i have to use member's name like this

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    author = message.author.name
    author = author.replace(" ", "")
    name = f"issue-{author}-{message.author.discriminator}"
    print(name)
```

But if message author has a Turkish character in his name, then this error shows up

```
line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u015f' in position 21: character maps to <undefined>
```

This wasn't happening 2, 3 weeks ago, i don't know what to do.

Comment: What encoding are you trying to use?

Comment: For example, if you are outputting UTF-8, then `\u015f` maps to `\xc5\x9f`. If you are outputting ISO-8859-9, then it maps to `\xfe`. If you are outputting to ISO-8859-1, then there is indeed no such character which it maps to.

Comment: I don't know the encoding, also i don't know how to change it, It is probably the encoding that PyCharm's automatically assigned encoding.

Comment: Is `return codecs.charmap_encode(...)` something you wrote, or just the line that triggers the error?

Comment: It triggers the error

Comment: Please provide an example of the code *you* wrote that triggers the error. See [mcve].

Comment: This isn't reproducible. What's `client`? But given the presence of the `print` function, the problem is likely that the encoding for your standard output is determined by the terminal your code runs in. That probably needs to be configured to UTF-8.

Comment: How can i change the encoding type?

Comment: In some sense, you don't have to. If your user sets their terminal correctly, your code will work. If you force the encoding to be UTF-8 and the user isn't prepared for that, they won't see the correct characters unless they set their terminal to expect UTF-8 anyway.